# Virtualbox udev rules SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device" vs SUBSYSTEM=="usb", with parameters

Tags: virtualbox, udev

In the VirtualBox manual (https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html), there is this fairly generic sentence: *«[...] `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-vboxdrv.rules`, a description file for `udev`, if that is present, which makes the USB devices accessible to all users in the `vboxusers` group.»*

I looked at the contents of the file:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d$ cat 60-vboxdrv.rules 
KERNEL=="vboxdrv", OWNER="root", GROUP="vboxusers", MODE="0660"
KERNEL=="vboxdrvu", OWNER="root", GROUP="root", MODE="0666"
KERNEL=="vboxnetctl", OWNER="root", GROUP="vboxusers", MODE="0660"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxCreateUSBNode.sh $major $minor $attr{bDeviceClass}"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", RUN+="/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxCreateUSBNode.sh $major $minor $attr{bDeviceClass}"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxCreateUSBNode.sh --remove $major $minor"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="remove", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", RUN+="/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxCreateUSBNode.sh --remove $major $minor"
```

There seem to be two identical rules when a USB device is inserted. The only difference is between `SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", ACTION=="add"` and `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device"`. Can anyone explain the difference?

The same when a device is removed.

Also, what are `$major` and `$minor`? Are these variables created by `udev`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being, I have found an answer to the second question, namely what `$major` and `$minor` are. First, they are mentioned in the [official udev documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html):

> $major, %M
>
> ```
> The kernel major number for the device.
> ```
>
> $minor, %m
>
> ```
> The kernel minor number for the device.
> ```

These are two variables that we can see associated with each device via:
`sudo udevadm monitor --udev --subsystem-match=usb --property`.
It outputs `udev` variables associated with a plugged in device.

Their explanation is here: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596000081/ch03s02.html

> The major number identifies the driver associated with the device.
> For example, /dev/null and /dev/zero are both managed by driver 1,
> whereas virtual consoles and serial terminals are managed by driver 4;
> similarly, both vcs1 and vcsa1 devices are managed by driver 7. The
> kernel uses the major number at open time to dispatch execution to the
> appropriate driver.
>
> The minor number is used only by the driver specified by the major
> number; other parts of the kernel don’t use it, and merely pass it
> along to the driver. It is common for a driver to control several
> devices (as shown in the listing); the minor number provides a way for
> the driver to differentiate among them.